# Changing swipe direction on iBooks (MacBook)

Tags: trackpad, books, macos

When I swipe from left-to-right on my Trackpad, iBook goes to the next page. When I swipe from right-to-left, it goes to the previous page.

Is there a way to reverse the order for this?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to set scroll direction to **Natural** under System Preferences app → Trackpad → Scroll & Zoom as shown in the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: So close! @stumped wants to change their trackpad scrolling. Just go to the Trackpad settings instead. It should also be noted changing this  will also reverse the scrolling everywhere on your Mac.